# how to fix this TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

how to fix this error

```
music.on('voiceStateUpdate',(lama, baru) => {
var state = null;  
let Role = baru.roles.find((r) => ["IRON", "BRONZE"].includes(r.name));
  const kategorikanal = '700743802574602260'
  const channelid = '700743824346972231'
  if(!lama.voiceChannel && !baru.voiceChannel) return;
  if(!lama.voiceChannel && baru.voiceChannel) {state = "join"}
  else if(lama.voiceChannel && !baru.voiceChannel) {state = "leave"}
  else if(lama.voiceChannel.id !== baru.voiceChannel.id) {state = "move"}
  else if(lama.voiceChannel.id == baru.voiceChannel.id) return;
  console.log(state);
//!baru.member.roles.has(allowedRole)
  if(baru.voiceChannelID === channelid || !baru.voiceChannelID === Role || Role !== null && Role !== '') {
console.log(baru.displayName + ' gabisabgo hrus ada rank ranked ');
   // const Role = baru.guild.roles.get("724997095236304987");
    baru.guild
    .createChannel(`${Role.name} | ${baru.user.username}`,"voice")
    .then(tempChannel => {
        tempChannel.overwritePermissions(baru.guild.defaultRole.id, {
   CONNECT: false,
})

    tempChannel.overwritePermissions(Role.id, {
        CONNECT: true
    })
      tempChannel.setParent(kategorikanal);
      baru.setVoiceChannel(tempChannel.id);
      tempChannel.setUserLimit("5");
      })
      
  .catch(console.error)
      
}
  if(lama.voiceChannelID || !lama.voiceChannelID === Role || Role !== null && Role !== '') {     
      console.log(lama.displayName + ' gabisabgo hrus ada rank ranked ');

      const voicelama = lama.guild.channels.get(lama.voiceChannelID);

    let Role = baru.roles.find((r) => ["IRON", "BRONZE"].includes(r.name));
      if(voicelama.name.startsWith(`${Role.name} | ${baru.user.username}`)){
      let sawadikap = `**${baru.user.username}'s**` + " **Team**"
      var koko = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setColor("#FF4654")
      .setThumbnail(`${baru.user.avatarURL}`)
      .addField('**Good Game Well Played**',`${sawadikap}`)
      .setFooter("@Valorant Indonesia Community." , 'https://i.imgur.com/yPWqxxu.png') 
       voicelama.delete()
      .then(function() {
        music.channels.get('725080861392896101').send(koko)
  })
      .catch(console.error);
  }
    }
  })
```

> **ERROR VIEW**

```
.createChannel(${Role.name} | ${baru.user.username},"voice")
 ^  TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you stepped through the code in debug mode? I recommend setting breakpoints, creating watches, and checking the value of the variables as you step through. If you don't feel comfortable doing so, can you please put in the following, and tell me what the console logs? :

```
console.log(Role)
console.log(Role.name)
```

Although `Role` is not `null`, The value of `Role.name` is `null`, meaning that it has no value assigned to it. That issue occurs here:

`let Role = baru.roles.find((r) => ["IRON", "BRONZE"].includes(r.name));`

So I see two possibilities:

1. No roles contain those names.
2. I thought that `find` should only result one result, but I can't seem to find good documentation of that method. Is it possible that both roles are found and a collection is returned? This would mean that there would be a collection of multiple roles, meaning that Role would not contain the data members that a Role object type would. This means that you would have to index one of the roles before using the name.

//

```
//if there isn't a matching role, then terminate the method.
if (Role == null)
{
    return;
}
//if there are multiple roles that match the criterion, just use the first one. 
//The alternative is that we could make it into a loop that handles it for all of them.
else if (Role instanceof Array)
{
    if (Role.length == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    Role = Role[0]
}
```

Add the above lines before calling  `baru.guild.createChannel`.

Comment: btw Role = null
but Role.name = TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null

Comment: What's the input? I edited my response to include some code to add.